# running a dll with activex objects with c#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, com, activex

Hi i have following c# code for configuring active x components as

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace Kosmala.Michal.ActiveXTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Class1.
    /// </summary>
    [ProgId("Dendrite.WebForce.MMP.Web.OurActiveX")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual), ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ControlEvents))] //Implementing interface that will be visible from JS
    [Guid("121C3E0E-DC6E-45dc-952B-A6617F0FAA32")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class ActiveXObject
    {
        private string myParam = "Empty"; 

        public ActiveXObject()
        {

        }

        public event ControlEventHandler OnClose;

        /// <summary>
        /// Opens application. Called from JS
        /// </summary>
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public void Open()
        {
            //TODO: Replace the try catch in aspx with try catch below. The problem is that js OnClose does not register.
            try
            {

                MessageBox.Show(myParam); //Show param that was passed from JS
                Thread.Sleep(2000); //Wait a little before closing. This is just to show the gap between calling OnClose event.
                Close(); //Close application

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //ExceptionHandling.AppException(e);
                throw e;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parameter visible from JS
        /// </summary>
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string MyParam
        {
            get
            {
                return myParam;
            }
            set
            {
                myParam = value;
            }
        }


        [ComVisible(true)]
        public void Close()
        {
            if(OnClose != null)
            {
                OnClose("http://otherwebsite.com"); //Calling event that will be catched in JS
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Event Attached"); //If no events are attached send message.
            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Register the class as a control and set it's CodeBase entry
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The registry key of the control</param>
        [ComRegisterFunction()]
        public static void RegisterClass ( string key )
        {
            // Strip off HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ from the passed key as I don't need it
            StringBuilder   sb = new StringBuilder ( key ) ;

            sb.Replace(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\","") ;
            // Open the CLSID\{guid} key for write access
            RegistryKey k   = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(sb.ToString(),true);

            // And create   the 'Control' key - this allows it to show up in
            // the ActiveX control container
            RegistryKey ctrl = k.CreateSubKey   ( "Control" ) ;
            ctrl.Close ( ) ;

            // Next create the CodeBase entry   - needed if not string named and GACced.
            RegistryKey inprocServer32 = k.OpenSubKey   ( "InprocServer32" , true ) ;
            inprocServer32.SetValue (   "CodeBase" , Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase ) ;
            inprocServer32.Close ( ) ;
                // Finally close the main   key
            k.Close (   ) ;
            MessageBox.Show("Registered");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called to unregister the control
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">Tke registry key</param>
        [ComUnregisterFunction()]
        public static void UnregisterClass ( string key )
        {
            StringBuilder   sb = new StringBuilder ( key ) ;
            sb.Replace(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\","") ;

            // Open HKCR\CLSID\{guid} for write access
            RegistryKey k = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(sb.ToString(),true);

            // Delete the 'Control' key, but don't throw an exception if it does not exist
            k.DeleteSubKey ( "Control" , false ) ;

            // Next open up InprocServer32
            //RegistryKey   inprocServer32 = 
            k.OpenSubKey (  "InprocServer32" , true ) ;

            // And delete the CodeBase key, again not throwing if missing
            k.DeleteSubKey ( "CodeBase" , false ) ;

            // Finally close the main key
            k.Close ( ) ;
            MessageBox.Show("UnRegistered");
        }



    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for events that will be visible from JavaScript
    /// </summary>
    public delegate void ControlEventHandler(string redirectUrl); 


    /// <summary>
    /// This interface shows events to javascript
    /// </summary>
    [Guid("68BD4E0D-D7BC-4cf6-BEB7-CAB950161E79")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface ControlEvents
    {
        //Add a DispIdAttribute to any members in the source interface to specify the COM DispId.
        [DispId(0x60020001)]
        void OnClose(string redirectUrl); //This method will be visible from JS
    }
}
```

and i have created the testpage .html as

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" > 

<html>
  <head>
    <title>WebForm1</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
    <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" Content="C#">
    <meta name=vs_defaultClientScript content="JavaScript">
    <meta name=vs_targetSchema content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
  </head>
  <body onload="OpenActiveX()">

  <!-- Our activeX object -->
  <OBJECT id="OurActiveX" name=”OurActiveX" classid="clsid:121C3E0E-DC6E-45dc-952B-A6617F0FAA32" VIEWASTEXT codebase="OurActiveX.cab"></OBJECT> 

  <!-- Attaching to an ActiveX event-->
<script language="javascript">
           function OurActiveX::OnClose(redirectionUrl)
       {
        alert(redirectionUrl);   <!-- http://otherwebsite.com should be returned-->
                    //window.location = redirectionUrl;
           }
</script>


<script language="javascript">
    //Passing parameters to ActiveX object and starting application
function OpenActiveX()
{
    try
    {
        document.OurActiveX.MyParam = "Hi I am here." //Passing parameter to the ActiveX
        document.OurActiveX.Open(); //Running method from activeX
    }
    catch(Err)
    {
        alert(Err.description);
    }
}   


</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

now when i am running the html page in internet explorer browser  i am getting following error as

OBJECT DOES NOT SUPPORT PROPERTY OR METHOD OPEN

can you help me to fix these problem

waiting for your valuable comments and responses

Comment: Is ActiveX enabled in your IE browser?

Comment: Did you register your ActiveX control using regasm?

Comment: @LajosArpad ya i have enabled it

Comment: @Hanssince i ma new i do not know how to register it ? can you provide me steps

Comment: @GowthamanSS: I've provided an answer with steps to register an ActiveX control.

Comment: @Hans thanks for ur information will do and update u

Comment: @Hans through code itself i am registering is that enough!

Comment: @GowthamanSS: What do you mean? Calling the RegisterClass() method directly without using regasm?

Comment: @Hans oh sorry!...i just asked is there any way to do soo....no probs thanks for your solution

Comment: @GowthamanSS: I do not exactly know what steps the regasm utiltiy executes to register an assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register your ActiveX control using
the Microsoft .Net Framework *regasm.exe* tool.

To register your ActiveX control use the following steps:

1. Open a command prompt.
2. Navigate the installation directory of the .Net framework
   you are targeting (e.g. c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework)
3. Type the following command

   **regasm.exe /tlb /codebase "path to your ActiveX.dll"**
4. Please note, if you are running on a x64 bit operating system
   you have to register your ActiveX control for x86 and x64
   internet explorer.
   For x64 internet explorer you have to navigate to the
   x64 directory of the .Net Framework you are targeting and
   execute the following command:

   **regasm.exe /tlb /codebase "path to your x64 ActiveX.dll"**

During registration of your ActiveX dll you should see a message box with
the message "Registered". Please not, if you compile your dlls with platform target "Any CPU"
you can use the same dll for registering.

Answer (score 2):

With your test page open in IE, open Internet Options from the tools button on the toolbar (in IE9), select the **Security** page, click the **Custom** button and scroll down to the "ActiveX Controls and plug-ins" section. You can enable prompting / enabling of ActiveX controls and scripting of them here.

By default, unsigned ActiveX controls are blocked in IE and signed ActiveX controls will raise a prompt.

Comment: I would suggest using the IE debugging tools - start script debugging, set a breakpoint, and make sure that your object is the right type on the line where .Open is being created. My hunch would be that the ActiveX control is never created - probably because of security restrictions. Are you seeing any security warnings in IE? You certainly would be if the control was being loaded - IE will not silently load an unsigned ActiveX component unless you had specifically allowed that in the advanced security settings.

Answer (score 1):

I would try un-registering the DLL, changing the GUID, and re-registering your class.  Since setting `MyParam` *appears* to work, it may be that `Open()` was added at a later time, and the interface definition is not getting re-registered.

Answer (score 0):

Remove static from the method names, and you will be alright !!